# Starting an Android Activity from an Listener defined in an external class file

Tags: android, android-activity, listener

I have an Activity `MyActivity` with a Button `MyButton`.

I want to attach a `MySpecialOnClickListener` to `MyButton`.

I write `MySpecialOnClickListener` in an external class file.

```
public class MySpecialOnClickListener extends ButtonHandler implements OnClickListener {
    public OnClickListenerWithSpeech (Context context) 
       { super.context = context; }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {  handleClick(view);  }
}
```

and ButtonHandler looks like this

```
public abstract class ButtonHandler {

    protected Context context;

    protected void handleClick (View view){
        if (view.getid()==R.id.button_B) {
            context.startActivity (new Intent(context, ActivityC.class));
        }
    }
}
```

I basically want to store all logic for Buttons in the ButtonHandler.

SO...as I said, I have the `MySpecialOnClickListener` defined in an external class file.

When I click `MyButton` I get the following fatal error.

```
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

So I can't start an activity normally from within a non-Activity. Fair enough.

However, if I change `MySpecialOnClickListener` to be an inner class in 'MyActivity' it works fine. Remember 'ButtonHandler' is still an external class file.  So it (where `ActivityC` is ultimately started from) doesn't change.

My question (finally) is: can someone explain the logic of why one is allowed and the other isn't. I presume its a scoping thing or something but I'm a bit confused. It seems the code to start the process of starting an activity has to *literally* be inside another Activity.

**EDIT - PROBLEM SOLVED**

See below. The location of the class is irrelevant. I just didn't pass in the context properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the ButtonHandler 'context' field isn´t associated with any activity context. So, when you attach the MySpecialOnClickListener instance to a button you create it passing the context parametener, isn´t???

something like this:

```
MySpecialOnClickListener listener = new MySpecialOnClickListener(MyActivity.this);
aButton.setOnClickListener( listener );
```

in this way you´re constructing the Button with the correct context...

Comment: Thank you for your help Franco. By messing about I figured it out just now but you were spot on.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you are not passing the Activity context to MySpecialOnClickListener. Could you show me the difference in the way you invoke the inner-class approach?

Comment: Thank you for helping Matthew. I figured out what I was doing wrong. But I didn't initially give enough info for you but you certainly asked the right question!.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies to those of you who tried to answer. It was my fault (and I didn't include the following info initially for people)

When I was passing in the context to the 'MySpecialOnClickListener' I would do:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new MySpecialOnClickListener(getApplicationContext()));
```

when I should have done:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new MySpecialOnClickListener(this));
```

So `getApplicationContext()` doesn't seem to get the "correct" context for the app.

Which leads me to my next question as to what `getApplicationContext()` actually returns :)